# How to reverse a string in place without reversing the punctuation?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to reverse the words in a string without any effect on punctuation.
This is my current code:

```
function reverse(str) {
    str = str.split("").reverse().join("");
    str = str.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
    console.log(str)
}; 

reverse("This is fun, hopefully.")
```

The result of the above function is `sihT si ,nuf .yllufepoh`
while I am trying to to get it like `sihT si nuf, yllufepoh.`

Comment: You cannot reverse a string keeping punctuation characters in place. But you can reverse every word with keeping punctuation in place. Change your question to more clearly express your intentions.

Comment: Unclear what this should do. What is the expected output of your example?

Comment: The result of above function is (sihT si ,nuf .yllufepoh). While i am trying to    to  get it like this(sihT si nuf, yllufepoh.)

Comment: What's the error? Please be more specific in both the error you are facing, and also provide the expected result.

Comment: @MSohaibKhan And please edit your question to add the requested information, don't just add it in the comments.

Comment: So you're _not_ trying to reverse the string, you are trying to reverse _each word_ in the string.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to reverse the words.

Comment: Your question is still too vague. are you expecting a function that can parse and account for any punctuation? So periods, commas, hyphens, etc.? This gets pretty complicated if you have a string with a ton of *different* punctuation characters in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach is to replace all sequences of letters with their reversed forms using *replace* and a regular expression, e.g.

```js
function reverseWords(s) {
  return s.replace(/[a-z]+/ig, function(w){return w.split('').reverse().join('')});
}

document.write(reverseWords("This is fun, hopefully.")); // sihT si nuf, yllufepoh.
```

If you wish to include numbers as word characters (w.g. W3C), then the regular expression should be:

/\w+/g

Answer (score 2):

Split the sentence on word boundaries, which doesn't consume any of the string,
then split each word into its letters (non-spaces with `\S`) using a lookahead `?=` so those aren't consumed.
Reverse the array of the letters, then rejoin them with no separator `.join("")`
and finally rejoin the sentence, again with no separator because the spaces between the words were retained when originally splitting on word boundaries.

```
var sentence = "This is fun, hopefully.";
sentence.split(/\b/)
        .map(w => w.split(/(?=\S)/)
                   .reverse()
                   .join("") )
    .join("");
```

Doing this in Chrome's javascript console produced the output:
`"sihT si nuf, yllufepoh."`

*Note* this doesn't correctly handle a run of punctuation. For example `hopefully!?` would become `yllufepoh?!`, reversing the punctuation too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do better with Regular Expressions, but this is a simple solution that I just wrote.

```
function reverse(str){
    var out = '';
    var word = '';
    for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
        // your punctuation characters
        if (',.!? '.indexOf(str[i]) == -1) word += str[i];
        else {
            out += word.split('').reverse().join('');
            out += str[i];
            word = '';
        }
    }
    return out;
}; 

console.log(reverse("This is fun, hopefully."));
```