# reverse string without affect special characters in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to reverse alphabet without the affect of a special character. I tried something but it doesn't seem to work. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<?php
function Remove($val){
      $r = strlen($val)-1;
      $j = 0;
      $pattern ='/[\'\/~`\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|;:"\<\>,\.\?\\\]/';
      while($j < $r){
        if(preg_match($pattern,$val[$j])){
             $j++;
         }
        else if(preg_match($pattern,$val[$r])){
            $r--;
        }else{
            $j++;
            $r--;
            list($val[$j],$val[$r]) = array($val[$j],$val[$r]);
        }
        }
    }
    $val = "<brinh!>";
    echo(Remove($val));
?>
```

Wanted output: <hnirb!>

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: i expect <hnirb!> instead <brinh!>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse a string in place without reversing the punctuation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191697/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-place-without-reversing-the-punctuation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution without regex would be:

```
function revert(string $input) : string {
    // get all characters; asuming ascii
    $chars = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
        if (ctype_alpha($input[$i])) {
            $chars[] = $input[$i];
        }
    }

    // replace characters
    for($i = 0;$i < strlen($input); $i++) {
        if (ctype_alpha($input[$i])) {
            $input[$i] = array_pop($chars);
        }
    }

    return $input;
}

$val = "<brinh!>";
echo revert($val);
```

Having two pointers, one running from left to right and one from right to left would also be possible. But much less readable.

Comment: why not? what did you insert? what was the output and what did you expect?

Comment: which php version are you running?

Comment: its php 7.2.14 @kuh-chan

Comment: @kuh-chan..i stop and try again the server..its wrk well..tq bro

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function reverse_string($string) {
  $len = strlen($string);
  $string_to_array = [];
  $special_characters = [];
  for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    // keep special characters and their current position in a new array
    if(preg_match('#[^a-zA-Z0-9]#', $string[$i])) {
      $pos = stripos($string, $string[$i]);
      $special_characters[$pos] = $string[$i];
    } else {
      // push only normal characters
      array_push($string_to_array, $string[$i]);
    }
    // reverse the normal characters
    $reversed_string = array_reverse($string_to_array);
  }
  // loop through special characters and add them to the reversed array at their original position
  foreach($special_characters as $key => $value) {
    array_splice($reversed_string, $key, 0, $value);
  }
  // convert array to string
  $array_to_string =  implode('', $reversed_string);
  return $array_to_string;
}

echo reverse_string('ab!t*cde$');
```